# Tuple as predicate argument (Repost)

Tags: notation, first-order-logic

Suppose for some $\epsilon, k > 0$

$ A=\{(x,y): x \geq k \land y\geq \epsilon / k\}$

$ B=\{(x,y): xy \geq \epsilon\}$

My goal is write $A \subseteq B$ as FOL statement, like

$P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$

where

$P(e)= e \in A$, and

$Q(e)= e \in B$

My understanding is that a predicate involving a single term is a property and a predicate involving 2 or more terms is a relation. My concern: I'm not claiming here that $x$ is related to $y$, rather the tuple $(x,y) \in A \Rightarrow (x,y) \in B$, since both $A$ and $B$ are sets of tuples. So the predicate $P$ or $Q$ should take a single parameter. So is it correct to write

$e=(x,y)$

$P(e)\Rightarrow Q(e)$

and, if it is equivalent to write

$P((x,y)) \Rightarrow Q((x,y))$

Also, the trick I used to prove this assertion is as follows:

Given:
$y \geq \epsilon / k$

$xy \geq x \epsilon /k$

since $x \geq k$ let $x = k+\delta$ where $\delta \geq 0$, then

$(k+\delta)\epsilon/k = \epsilon + \delta\epsilon/k \geq \epsilon$

therefore, $xy \geq x \epsilon /k \geq \epsilon$

Is this correct?

Comment: $\exists\varepsilon,k{>}0\;\forall x \forall y\; (x \geq k \land y\geq \frac{\varepsilon}k \Rightarrow xy \geq \varepsilon).$

Comment: @ryang Better to leave $k, \epsilon$ as parameters. @ OP The last part of the proof is screwy. There’s no need for $\delta$. If $x\ge a, y\ge b$ with $a, b\gt 0$, then $x y\ge a b$.

Comment: @BrianO My comment pertains only to the first four lines of the Question (up to "$A \subseteq B$"). And, since I'm not quite sure what the OP is wanting, I tossed out the suggestion, without comment, *in case* it is relevant to their query and helps in some way.

Comment: @ryang Maybe I  should have said “Probably it’s better” :) But, it is: OP needs to express $A\subseteq B$ in FOL, which begins with a universal quantifier.(over ordered pairs), and doesn’t include the introduction of $k, \epsilon$, which I read as “Let…” or “Suppose…”.

Comment: Oh, I totally agree. I'd deliberately avoided further comment because whatever context had been provided remains murky to me, so my suggestion is not based on any context, and is really just a literal symbolisation of their "for some ϵ,k" (from lines 1-4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My concern: I'm not claiming here that x is related to y, rather the tuple (x,y)∈A⇒(x,y)∈B, since both A and B are sets of tuples.

... So you're claiming that $A$ and $B$ are relations. Relation *means* set of tuples, and nothing else than that. There needs to be no intuitive semantic connection between the components of a tuple for them to count as "related"; simply the fact that they are contained as a tuple in the set means, by definition, that they are in relation.

What you propose is *not* correct. Arguments of predicates must be individuals. Technically one could define a universe of discourse where the individuals are tuples of numbers rather than numbers themselves, but then the individuals that can be quantified over and referenced with variables would be the tuples, and not the components inside the tuples. Something like $P((x,y))$ is not possible, because $(x,y)$ must be an individual term to occur as a predicate argument, and there is no rule that allows for a construction of such an expression where two variables are put in a tuple to make a new individual term.

It is also not necessary. Your sets $A, B$ are a perfectly adequate use case for binary predicates. $\forall x \forall y (A(x,y) \Rightarrow B(x,y))$ correctly captures the subset relation.